# Why Is My Mesh Rendering Into A Blob? It Is Supposed To Be A Macaron

Tags: rendering, mesh

[image]

My mesh is rendering as a blob. It is supposed to be a macaron. I am using cycles to render.

What is the problem here?

https://workupload.com/file/Pnes5zTXYbg

Comment: Hello, hard to guess, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The file is too big to upload. It gave me an error.

Comment: only keep the important object, and maybe use another platform like workupload?

Comment: https://workupload.com/file/Pnes5zTXYbg

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the scale of your objects in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) otherwise your *Displacement* node you're using in your materials will mess up the dimensions.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so so much! I was struggling with this for days. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You also have around 129,000 duplicate vertices on each "Macaron Feet Top" object and 2,300 on each "Macaron Shell Top" object which won't help! In fact merging them on each object reduces your blend file size by half!